# Convolving two images

Tags: convolution

This is my coding for convolving my image and patch of 16*16 of same image.I changed my coding now.But I am getting only image full of white pixels? This is my changed coding

```
clear all
close all

I=imread('E:\double.jpg');
subplot(3,2,1);
imshow(I);
title('Original');

%gray conversion
J = rgb2gray(I);
subplot(3,2,2);
imshow(J);
title('Gray');

K = double(J);

%size of the image
[A B]=size(J);
%patch definition
patch_size = 16;

        temp = J(1:patch_size, 1:patch_size);
        subplot(3,2,3);
        imshow(temp);
        title('kernel');
        temp1 = double(temp);

        C = conv2(temp1,K);
        subplot(3,2,4);       
        imshow(C);
        title('Convolved image');
```

Comment: What are `i` and `j` doing? Are you performing many convolutions for different patches? Please explain that in your question. Because if you're really just trying to convolve the image with a single patch of itself then you don't need any loops?

Comment: How come you can't use `imfilter`?

Comment: Can you say how to used imfilter?

Comment: Simply do `out = imfilter(in, patch, 'replicate');`  `in` is the input image - preferably in `uint8` format and `in` is the patch, kernel or impulse response of the filter you would like to filter the image.  In your case, `patch` would be `temp`.